# MySQL query join across 4 tables on different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables (stripped down to relevant columns for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE `papers` (
   `paper_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`paper_id`)
);
INSERT INTO papers ( paper_id ) VALUES(1001);
INSERT INTO papers ( paper_id ) VALUES(1002);   
INSERT INTO papers ( paper_id ) VALUES(1003);
INSERT INTO papers ( paper_id ) VALUES(1004);
INSERT INTO papers ( paper_id ) VALUES(1005);
INSERT INTO papers ( paper_id ) VALUES(1006);

CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
);
INSERT INTO questions ( type_id ) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO questions ( type_id ) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO questions ( type_id ) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO questions ( type_id ) VALUES(3);

CREATE TABLE `question_depends` (
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `depends_question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `depends_answer_val` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`,`depends_question_id`)
);
INSERT INTO question_depends ( question_id, depends_question_id, depends_answer_val ) VALUES(3, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO question_depends ( question_id, depends_question_id, depends_answer_val ) VALUES(2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO question_depends ( question_id, depends_question_id, depends_answer_val ) VALUES(3, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `paper_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer_val` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`paper_id`,`question_id`)
); 
INSERT INTO answers ( paper_id, question_id, answer_val ) VALUES(1002, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO answers ( paper_id, question_id, answer_val ) VALUES(1002, 4, 0);
INSERT INTO answers ( paper_id, question_id, answer_val ) VALUES(1004, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO answers ( paper_id, question_id, answer_val ) VALUES(1004, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO answers ( paper_id, question_id, answer_val ) VALUES(1005, 1, 1);
```

I am trying to come up with a single query that shows all data for all possible combinations:

1. All papers ID's should be output at least once
2. A given paper_id may or may not have answers and may or may not have dependencies
3. The ultimate goal is to see if each dependency question is answered and if so if the answer val matches the dependencies answer val for each paper id along with determining if a paper_id has dependency questions or not and if any questions are not answered (whether or not they have dependencies)
4. I can adjust tables/data if needed

I came close with:

```
select P.paper_id as P_PID,
  A.paper_id as A_PID,
  A.question_id as A_QID,
  A.answer_val as A_VAL,
  QD.question_id as QD_QID,
  QD.depends_question_id AS QD_DQID,
  QD.depends_answer_val AS QD_VAL,
  Q.type_id AS Q_TYPE
from papers P
left join answers A on A.paper_id = P.paper_id
left join question_depends QD on QD.depends_question_id = A.question_id
left join questions Q on Q.question_id = QD.question_id
UNION
select NULL AS P_PID,
  NULL AS A_PID,
  A.question_id as A_QID,
  A.answer_val as A_VAL,
  QD.question_id as QD_QID,
  QD.depends_question_id AS QD_DQID,
  QD.depends_answer_val AS QD_VAL,
  Q.type_id AS Q_TYPE
from question_depends QD
left join answers A on QD.depends_question_id = A.question_id
left join questions Q on Q.question_id = QD.question_id
  where A.question_id IS NULL
```

...but the output has the answer data for EVERY row of each paper_id not just the ones for that paper_id. Any thoughts appreciated! Using this small sample data set the above select outputs:

```
P_PID   A_PID   A_QID   A_VAL   QD_QID  QD_DQID QD_VAL  Q_TYPE
1001                            
1002    1002    1       1       2       1       1       2
1002    1002    1       1       3       1       0       1
1002    1002    4       0       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1003    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1004    1004    1       0       2       1       1       2
1004    1004    1       0       3       1       0       1
1004    1004    3       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1005    1005    1       1       2       1       1       2
1005    1005    1       1       3       1       0       1
1006    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The ideal output (if I didn't typo anything) would be:

```
P_PID   A_PID   A_QID   A_VAL   QD_QID  QD_DQID QD_VAL  Q_TYPE
1001    NULL    NULL    NULL    2       1       1       2
1001    NULL    NULL    NULL    3       1       0       1
1002    1002    1       1       2       1       1       2 
1002    NULL    NULL    NULL    3       1       0       1
1002    1002    4       0       NULL    NULL    NULL    3
1003    NULL    NULL    NULL    2       1       1       2
1003    NULL    NULL    NULL    3       1       0       1
1004    1004    1       0       2       1       1       2 
1004    NULL    NULL    NULL    3       1       0       1
1004    1004    3       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    1
1005    1005    1       1       2       1       1       2
1005    NULL    NULL    NULL    3       1       0       1
1006    NULL    NULL    NULL    2       1       1       2
1006    NULL    NULL    NULL    3       1       0       1
```

Comment: can you show us your expected result?

Comment: I hope some day I will not feel the need to upvote a question only because it contains the relevant tables DDL+DML for sample data. Until that day, here are free 5 reputation points. Don't spend them all in one place... :-)

Comment: Can you explain the expected rows for 1001, 1003 and 1006? They had no answers... Is "no answer" the same is wrong answer? Then, why is it "3 1 0" in these, and not "3 1 1" (they answer to question 1 could be 1 or 0) - or is no answer always "answer 0"? But then, why is "2 1 1" there ("no answer" to "1" should get the dependency " x 1 0", right?). Also: you should not try to get "null"-rows for the "2nd" dependency. If you want to hide these, hide (=not print) them in the client. The value is known, so don't make it null. Also, the last left join should be to A.question_id, not QD.question_id.

Comment: The intent is to get all dependency questions for each paper_id (whether or not they have answers). We filter them by type but that is not reflected here to keep things simpler. So in essence no answer is the same as wrong answer. The 'A' values are the answers. The 'QD' are the dependencies. So on a screen where question 3 is potentially displayed, it is only displayed for a given paper_id IF ALL of the question 3 dependencies are met (1 has an answer of 0 in the "3 1 0" case).

Comment: We do not know in advance which paper_id's or questions will be selected for a given screen in advance, so we need to know ALL the possible dependencies for a given paper_id (or list of paper_id's) and then based on the questions selected for those, whether or not each applicable questions dependencies were answered for that paper_id. If any one of the dependencies is not met, the parent question is not displayed for that paper_id. Hopefully all this makes some sense. It is complicated.

Comment: An alternative might be a count of expected dependencies by question_id and a count of each paper_id towards meeting those dependencies for each paper_id in answers in a single query.

Comment: The third insert on question_depends conflicts the primary key and is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

"Divide et impera". Split the problem into three cases.

```
 SELECT /*Answers and no depends*/ p.paper_id AS p_pid,
  a.paper_id AS a_pid,
  a.question_id AS a_qid,
  a.answer_val AS a_val,
  qd.question_id AS qd_qid,
  qd.depends_question_id AS qd_dqid,
  qd.depends_answer_val AS qd_val,
  q.type_id AS q_type
 FROM papers p
 JOIN answers a 
    ON a.paper_id = p.paper_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN question_depends qd 
    ON  a.question_id = qd.depends_question_id 
        AND 
        a.answer_val = qd.depends_answer_val
 LEFT OUTER JOIN questions q 
    ON q.question_id = a.question_id
 WHERE qd.question_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT /*Answers and depends*/ p.paper_id AS p_pid,
  a.paper_id AS a_pid,
  a.question_id AS a_qid,
  a.answer_val AS a_val,
  qd.question_id AS qd_qid,
  qd.depends_question_id AS qd_dqid,
  qd.depends_answer_val AS qd_val,
  q.type_id AS q_type
 FROM papers p
 JOIN answers a 
    ON a.paper_id = p.paper_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN question_depends qd 
    ON  a.question_id = qd.depends_question_id 
        AND 
        a.answer_val = qd.depends_answer_val
 LEFT OUTER JOIN questions q 
    ON q.question_id = qd.question_id
 WHERE qd.question_id IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT /*Missing answer*/ p.paper_id AS p_pid,
  a.paper_id AS a_pid,
  a.question_id AS a_qid,
  a.answer_val AS a_val,
  qd.question_id AS qd_qid,
  qd.depends_question_id AS qd_dqid,
  qd.depends_answer_val AS qd_val,
  q.type_id AS q_type
 FROM papers p
 CROSS JOIN question_depends qd
 JOIN questions q 
    ON q.question_id = qd.question_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN answers a 
    ON a.paper_id = p.paper_id
        AND
        a.question_id = qd.depends_question_id
        AND
        a.answer_val = qd.depends_answer_val
 WHERE a.question_id IS NULL 
 ORDER BY 1, 7 DESC;
```

You may check the result on SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbd3a9/3